# Virsh: Different XML with edit than dumpxml. Why?

Tags: virtualization, libvirt

I'm trying to fetch the VNC access data from a virtual machine managed by libVirt. However, when I run `virsh dumpxml $machine`, the vnc passwd is missing:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
```

Checking the same using `virsh edit $machine`, I see the password is actually there:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' passwd='asdf'/>
```

Why is this? Is this intentional (what reason?), or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional; look for VIR_DOMAIN_XML_SECURE flag in libvirt sources.